# How to edit and submit for review of my closed questions to get my self unbanned?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

I am banned. So I am trying harder to get unbanned by increasing my reputation and also editing my previous questions. But some of my questions are closed and how to get these questions to be edited and reviewed by the moderators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed questions can be edited. Once you edit your closed question, it will be reviewed by community via [Reopen votes queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen). So edit your questions and improve it. Also, have a look at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/187824) for more info.

Comment: thanks a lot hope my ban will be removed soon :)