# Will anyone notice that I edited my (closed) question?

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen, bump

I asked a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430610/workflow-tools-for-frontend-javascript-development-test-and-production), and it was closed as non constructive.

I then edited it, that is, I completely rewrote it, trying to make it convey that what I'm asking is: "how do I accomplish this?"

I've proofread my edited question, and now I'm quite positive that it's constructive, in that it allows for answers of the form "you cannot accomplish this" or, "you can accomplish this by doing that".

Now that I marked my question to be reopened, who will ever notice that the question was significantly edited and marked to be reopened?

Should I just sit and hope for people to stumble upon my question and casually notice that, though it was closed, it was edited **after** being closed, and thus it may be worth checking if it still deserves to say closed or if it may be worth reopening, or is there a way to capture people's attention on the subject?

Comment: It should, plausibly, end up in the [review-reopen queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) for users with enough reputation to access it.

Comment: Related if not dup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172114/187824

Comment: @hims056 dup? I'm not banned! (I didn't even know one could get banned...)

Comment: @giorgian To be fair, hims056 did say "related", rather than duplicate. =)

Comment: @giorgian - Whatever the answer will remain same. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Your edit bumps your question to the front page and, as your edit was substantial, automatically puts it in the re-open queue.

The bump or the fact that you posted it here has gained you two re-open votes already. Unfortunately for you, [no-one who saw it in the re-open queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/1727022) believed that it should be re-opened.

The reason is, I believe, your last sentence:

> Is there a tool, or a set of tools, or some different way to organize
>   my code, so that it's possible to pass from the development version to
>   the production one (which will also be minimized)?

Although your edit was a good one, you're still on the edge of asking for product recommendations. When writing a question you have to consider how other people will perceive it. There are a number of red flags that will make people more likely to close a question as "not constructive". This sentence is one of them.

I don't think you're that far off a great question and your question may be re-opened in any case. I'm not entirely certain what you can do to change this but I would probably remove the reference to tools. If there is a tool that does the job you want them someone might suggest is anyway without being specifically asked.

Comment: "as your edit was substantial" — Do you mean that there's a minimum diff threshold for an edit to put a closed question in the re-open queue?

Comment: Yes @giorgian; I don't know what it is but empirically, it seems to be a percentage rather than an absolute number. It's not the sort of thing that, if I were SE, I would share. You don't want people doing the absolute minimum necessary, you want them to do the best they can to improve their question in one go. In any case I suspect you were well over whatever limit there is.

Answer (score 2):

It should, plausibly, end up in the [review-reopen queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen) for users with [enough reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) to access it. Also, as you've posted it here, it is very likely to garner you some attention. ;)